What are font pairing options for Neue Haas Grotesk that support Korean?
For a design challenge I am looking for a viable partner font to Neue Haas Grotesk to use for Korean text to go next to it. Everything I have found is visibly too different to be placed right next to text in Latin Neue Haas Grotesk letters.
The font being Hanja compatible is a non-factor, as Hangul is the only script used.
Thanks in advance!

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  This is a very opinion based question, and these are not generally a good fit for this website.  Can you at least please show what you have tried, and explain what you mean when you say "visibly too different".  Without seeing anything it's very hard to answer this.  Thanks.
